# I am not able generate csr from aws acm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, csr

I have a domain which i bought on Godaddy, and i deployed the website on amazon ec2, now i am trying to add ssl certificate to my domain and i am not able to generate CSR from the amazon AWS ACM which i need to give as input csr in Godaddy site. When i followed the below documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PcaGetCsr.html, i could not generate the CSR.

Instructions sent by godday
https://in.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-aws-server-32075
, but i m not using load balancer for my ec2 instance.
[image]

Comment: If you want ACM to generate and manage an SSL certificate, you don't need to manually create a CSR.

Comment: I have SSL certificate, I want to attach this car to that

Comment: Then simply use ACM to import the existing certificate. You'll need the certificate body, private key, and cert chain.

Comment: I am supposed to add the csr from aws to GoDaddy, and I am not allowed to bring those SSL to acm

Comment: In aws though I followed the guidelines, there is no csr showing up at end

Comment: You just said that you already have an SSL certificate. That seems incompatible with now wanting to create a CSR. Having a CSR is a pre-requisite for generating a certificate.

Comment: The csr is generated by GoDaddy , and the team of GoDaddy said to link the csr from aws to domain so that it becomes active

Comment: It would help for you to include the instructions that GoDaddy sent to you, and any links that they asked you to follow.

Comment: i have included the instruction from the godaddy, but their tech support told me to generate a csr from aws and paste it in the above image input csr

Comment: also when i downloaded zip folder of ssl, i get two certificates and a pem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used this command to generate a csr inside ec2 server instance

```
sudo openssl req -new -key /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key -out /home/bitnami/digitowork/cert.csr
```

Thank you for the help and contribution from stackoverflow